# Why does an asterisk return a forbidden page?

Tags: php, apache

I'm using XAMPP with Apache/2.4.0 and PHP/5.6.3 and I've noticed that an asterisk (*) as the first character in a URL like `http://localhost/*` causes apache to return an access forbidden page before running PHP. I haven't noticed any other websites making use of the asterisk character for anything so I know it must be an invalid character for some reason or another but I can't find anything on it. Does anybody know how to override this in xampp so I can do my own custom error management in PHP?

Comment: If we can't find something on how to override this then the bounty is yours. But I am interested in how to override this behavior. I know facebook is able to override and parse it.

Comment: What would you rather happen with an `*` character?

Comment: I would like to deliver my own custom error page from PHP.

Comment: Definitely a tricky one. I just spent another 30 minutes on it and can't seem to get it to accept. I can get exclamation points working pretty easily with mod_rewrite though.

Answer (score 2):

To customize your errors pages :

Edit the file **conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf**
Update the line that contains **ErrorDocument 403**, you have 3 differents flavor :

Flavor 1, **plain text**:                `ErrorDocument 403 "What are you doing here ??"`

Flavor 2, **local redirects**:       `ErrorDocument 403 "/error/myCustom403ErrorPage.html"`

Flavor 3, **external redirects**: `ErrorDocument 403 "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403"`

**Note:** You must restart Apache server after *.conf update
The asterisk is a reserved character, it is used by Apache for this reason :
"*On systems with multiple users, each user can be permitted to have a web site in their home directory using the UserDir directive*"
You can read This documentation from Apache to know in what asterisk is really used :) [Apache - Per-user web directories](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/howto/public_html.html)

**UPDATE:**
If you want to execute a php script as error page (you can use flavor 3)

```
ErrorDocument 403 "http://localhost/customWebAppError/error403.php"
```

**UPDATE**

Create your custom error page **ERROR_403.html**

Put it under **xampp/apache/error**

Update **httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf** by `ErrorDocument 403 /error/ERROR_403.html`

Create an **iframe** or an **ajax** request inside your **ERROR_403.html** that can communicates with your server and deliver custom response

Comment: This doesn't allow me to run PHP as the error page. Is there anyway to deliver the PHP generated dynamic content?

Comment: Redirecting an error generating URL to another is not the same as actually parsing the error generating URL. I would want the error page to reflect the URL causing the error.

Comment: The asterisk is a special character on Apache's configuration file but it is allowed in the URL. At least, it serves a file named `*` without any problem.

Comment: That is still redirection and would result in a URL with no asterisk in the URL once it gets to PHP. I've awarded the bounty since this was the most helpful but I'm still at a loss as to how to directly parse that page with PHP by disabling Apache's error checking in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it's a reserved character.

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html

> The asterisk ("*", ASCII 2A hex) and exclamation mark ("!" , ASCII 21 hex) are reserved for use as having special signifiance within specific schemes.

Explanation (brief...):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

> Section 2, on characters, has been rewritten to explain what
> characters are reserved, when they are reserved, and why they are
> reserved, even when they are not used as delimiters by the generic
> syntax.  The mark characters that are typically unsafe to decode,
> including the exclamation mark ("!"), asterisk ("*"), single-quote
> ("'"), and open and close parentheses ("(" and ")"), have been moved
> to the reserved set in order to clarify the distinction between
> reserved and unreserved and, hopefully, to answer the most common
> question of scheme designers.  Likewise, the section on
> percent-encoded characters has been rewritten, and URI normalizers
> are now given license to decode any percent-encoded octets

I've tested with mod_rewrite, and still a 403 error. It does seem to work in a query string, though: `?whatever*`

Answer (score 0):

As it works on my Windows using php and apache binaries and custom configuration, as it works the same way on my linux server, I should assume that it has to be a problem with the default XAMPP configuration.

**You should try to disable some apache or php modules that could avoid a correct gestion of url. (cache, accelerator, ...)**

For information, I have done my tests using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1
```