# does apache return a custom error page on a 400 with a malformed host header?

Tags: php, apache, cookies, httpd.conf, apache-config

Does apache return a custom error page on a 400 with a malformed host header?
if no then can we edit default error page for 400 bad request?
error message 
"Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit."

cookie : xyz.

server details:....

I dont want to show cookie value and server details.

i know how to hide server details(by switching serversignature Off in httpd.conf).
how to hide cookie?

Comment: see my response http://stackoverflow.com/a/28602305/4098311

Comment: it does not solve my problem. i want to hide cookie value.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the cookie value? The only person you are revealing it to will be the person who sent the value to your server in the first place.

Comment: Yes i know, but i wanted to know whether is there any way to hide it?